# Errors - bootstrap GLM model - glmmBoot package

Tags: glm, glmmtmb

I'm trying to run a bootstrap resampling on a GLM model, but I keep running into errors and I can't find any solution online.

The first problem in which I ran into is "variable lenght differs" when i try to use a normalized variable (sub.size_z) and a continuous variable trasformed into factor (hours). I checked my dataset and there are no NAs anywhere, so i don't know how to tackle the problem.
[image]

The second error is "Error: Naming mismatch from base to list of coefs", which happens when i try to run the bootstrap using a GLM without having trasformed the variables that i previously mentioned.

[image]

Can anyone point me towards a solution? Thanks a lot!

Here's the code I used!

```
data <-read.delim2("C:/Users/BRIZ_/Desktop/analisi scratching/Hypothesis 3/Hypothesis 3/database.txt")


library(car)
library(lme4)
library(MASS)
library(dplyr)
library(blmeco)
library(MuMIn)
library(lmerTest)
library(AER)
library(DHARMa)

sub.size_z<-scale(sub.size, center=TRUE,scale=TRUE)
hours<- as.factor(hour)


modelboot<-glmmTMB(sc.count~ offset(log(DURATION)) + hours + general.activity + sub.size_z + approach5+ id,data=data, family=genpois(link = "log"))
summary(modelboot)

bootstrap_model(modelboot,base_data=data,resamples =100)
```

Comment: Hi, please don't post screenshots of code. They're not searchable and they're not paste-able if we want to debug. Instead, post the code itself—particularly, a [mre]. (See [ask].)

Comment: I added the code, sorry :)